# Unable to generate service tokens - Permission denied on resource

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to follow documentation mentioned here in Google documentation: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token

I have tried both programmatic and API call method, but I get the same response.

```
$ curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=abc-def-api-4yuwqeg56fq-ew.a.run.app" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"

Failed to generate identity token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

With libraries, I am getting the same error:

```
>>> id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 377, in _call_metadata_identity_endpoint
    id_token = _metadata.get(request, path, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 182, in get
    raise exceptions.TransportError(
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ('Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https%3A%2F%2Fabc-def-api-4yuwqeg56fq-ew.a.run.app&format=full from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 403 Response:\nb"Failed to generate identity token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).\\n"', <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7f4c9f9aa7d0>)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/oauth2/id_token.py", line 340, in fetch_id_token
    id_token_credentials.refresh(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 398, in refresh
    self.token, self.expiry = self._call_metadata_identity_endpoint(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 380, in _call_metadata_identity_endpoint
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https%3A%2F%2Fabc-def-api-4yuwqeg56fq-ew.a.run.app&format=full from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 403 Response:\nb"Failed to generate identity token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).\\n"', <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7f4c9f9aa7d0>)
>>>
```

I have put audience as the Cloud Run URL.

Am I not able to understand what's wrong and what I can do to get it right. Any pointers / guidance would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: The error message (stack trace) tells you which permission you need `iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken`. That permission is part of the role `Service Account Token Creator`. See @mrthompson's answer. Another possibility is that you misspelled the Cloud Run service URL.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to assign the following role, `Service Account Token Creator`, to the account that you are using to execute the curl?

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#token-creator-role

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the roles assigned to your user and you can add the  role which has iam.serviceAccounts.create permission. If required you can also create a custom role manually adding this permission to it and then assigning it to the user.

As john hanely suggested you need iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken permission.
Also as per the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#iam.serviceAccountOpenIdTokenCreator), the below three roles have the permission of iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken. Add any of these permissions as per your requirement and try again.

**Service Account OpenID Connect Identity Token Creator**

(roles/iam.serviceAccountOpenIdTokenCreator)

**Service Account Token Creator**

(roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator)

**Workload Identity User**

(roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser)

You can also refer to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateIdToken) to understand further about serviceAccounts.generateIdToken